# Website redirects to old hosting on computer but to new hosting on phone

Tags: dns, redirection

I recently migrated the DNS settings of my website to a new hosting provider (Google Firebase).

After 48 hours, the website gets indeed redirected when I visit it on my phone. On the computer however it appears to be still redirecting to the old website.

I tried to flush my dns by opening `cmd` and typing `ipconfig/flushdns` but this did not seem to work. What could be other causes?

I also tried:

- X. `nslookup mywebsite`
- Y. `nslookup mywebsite 1.1.1.1`
- Z. `nslookup mywebsite 8.8.8.8`

and found that Y and Z point to the same desired A-record ip address but X not.

Comment: Please try these commands: `nslookup yourwebsite.com`, `nslookup yourwebsite.com 1.1.1.1`, `nslookup yourwebsite.com 8.8.8.8` (substitute `yourwebsite.com` with actual URL) and post results ([edit] your question)

Comment: I dont want to give away the ip addresses, but basically I get that for the addresses for 1)  ***.15 and ***.5. For 2) I get a non-authoritative answer with addresses ***.195 and ***.195. For 3) I get the same as for 2). The A records should be pointing to 2 and 3 and not to 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked you in the comments to execute three `nslookup` commands that query DNS servers for IP of the server that hosts your website:

1. `nslookup yourwebsite.com` - queries your default DNS
2. `nslookup yourwebsite.com 1.1.1.1` - queries CloudFlare DNS
3. `nslookup yourwebsite.com 8.8.8.8` - queries Google DNS

So your default DNS is returning outdated information, while Google and CloudFlare DNS have already updated. I'd suggest switching to some more reliable DNS provider. [CloudFlare](https://1.1.1.1/) has a nice website that includes DNS configuration guides.

Comment: Who provides exactly the DNS? The telecom company that I use to register my domain?

Comment: Usually the default DNS is provided by your ISP. If you have a router, then your devices probably send all DNS requests to the router, which in turn queries ISP's public DNS. `ipconfig` command will return DNS address that you're using among other data. If it's a local IP, then that device (router, probably) acts as a DNS server, probably forwarding queries to ISP DNS as I said earlier.

Comment: Any way to resolve that?

Comment: You can only wait, I guess - it's a problem at ISP's end, not yours. Switching to a different DNS will help (and improve domain name resolution speed, and possible improve your browsing privacy), but other people using the same DNS will still face the issue until changes propagate to that server.